# linked in IN.API.Raw

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

```
/people-search:(people:(id,first-name,last-name,date-of-birth,summary,industry,group-memberships,job-bookmarks,interests,associations,public-profile-url,picture-url,headline))?keyword=retail&count=500
```

the above search gets me all my connections when it is just suppost to get the ones in retail.

```
?keyword=cytdcytxyrtr4dftubiugiuguukjkjp
```

this does the same...

I am glad that I get 'a' result but why aren't params working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's "keywords" plural. Does that fix things?